# Effective sample size after applyting butterworth filter

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, p-value, sample-size, independence

I have a signal `s` with a total length of `N*D` in time, which I break into `N` observations of dimension `D` (`s[0:D-1]`, `s[D:2D-1]`, etc.). I assume these `N` observations are independent. I use these observations as an input to a linear logit regression model predicting another set of `N` binary values corresponding to these observations, and test this model against the null hypothesis of no relationship between input and output to get a pvalue for my linear model.

Now, before doing this, I like to filter the data (e.g. using butterworth) to remove low frequency drift and high frequency noise. However, I have a feeling that by doing this I introduce systematic correlation into the sequence, which means I cannot assume I have `N` independent observations anymore.

My questions:

- How can I calculate the effective number of independent samples?
- How can I introduce this number to my hypothesis testing procedure so that I correct the pvalue I calculate?

Comment: (1) What do you mean by a "sample" in this context? (2) What method are you using that requires an *explanatory* variable, as $s$ seems to be, to consist of independent values?

Comment: @whuber The s[0:D-1], s[D:2D-1], ... are my samples. I am not sure I understand your second point. s is a time series and the values are not really independent for multiple reasons. For instance, the low frequency drift obviously correlates the D dimensional observations that are closer together in time. But since what I am interested in is not, for the most part, the absolute values in each observation but the relationship between the dimensions (among other reasons), as far as my model is concerned, each D dimensional observation can be assumed to be independently sampled from some process.

Comment: For instance, you can imagine that for some of the $D$-dimensional observations (i.e. $x$), the general trend is that $x_i>x_{i+1} | 0\leq i<D-1$, whereas for others $x_i<x_{i+1}$ and these trends can predict my dependent binary value (output of my logit model).